# SSIS How to ignore the Flat File Missing Failure?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm still learning SSIS.

I design a package that reads a flat file from a source folder, inserts the data into a database and then moves the flat file to an archived folder.

This workflow works great except if there is no files in the source folder. How do you ensure the package does not fail if the file is not in the source folder? I know that sounds silly, but the file not being in the source is intended in my mind and I don't want to disable the data flow failure exceptions because that checks if the data is valid if the file is there.

I am using SQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the Data Flow task inside of a Foreach (File) Enumerator that looks for whatever your source file is.

If no match is found, then the Data Flow will never fire and thus, won't error out.